# Migrating from Leakcanary 1.* to 2.* Converting LeakTrace to StackTrace

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am trying to migrate from LeakCanary version 1.* to version 2.* version one used to have `AnalysisResult.leakTraceAsFakeException` but now I can't seem to be able to find a similar behavior I am stuck after creating my custom FakeException but I am unable to convert the LeakTrace to a StackTrace 
I am following this [link](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#uploading-to-bugsnag) but I am not using BugSnag in my application

Answer (score 2):

This capability was removed from LeakCanary 2, but you can recreate it for your own needs. See the code in LeakCanary 1.6: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/v1.6.3/leakcanary-analyzer/src/main/java/com/squareup/leakcanary/AnalysisResult.java#L104-L133

```
public @NonNull RuntimeException leakTraceAsFakeException() {
  if (!leakFound) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
        "leakTraceAsFakeException() can only be called when leakFound is true");
  }
  LeakTraceElement firstElement = leakTrace.elements.get(0);
  String rootSimpleName = classSimpleName(firstElement.className);
  String leakSimpleName = classSimpleName(className);

  String exceptionMessage = leakSimpleName
      + " leak from "
      + rootSimpleName
      + " (holder="
      + firstElement.holder
      + ", type="
      + firstElement.type
      + ")";
  RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException(exceptionMessage);

  StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new StackTraceElement[leakTrace.elements.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (LeakTraceElement element : leakTrace.elements) {
    String methodName = element.referenceName != null ? element.referenceName : "leaking";
    String file = classSimpleName(element.className) + ".java";
    stackTrace[i] = new StackTraceElement(element.className, methodName, file, 42);
    i++;
  }
  exception.setStackTrace(stackTrace);
  return exception;
}
```

The biggest difference between 1.6 and 2 is that an analysis result used to have one leaktrace (=> converts to one stacktrace) but now LeakCanary can find many leaks at once so the analysis result will have several leaks, you'll want to create a stacktrace for each.